# Can Bard's Q stun more than 2 enemy champions with a single cast?

Tags: league-of-legends

Bard's Unique Eternals include one titled Cosmic Catches with a requirement of "Multiple (2+) enemy champions stunned with Cosmic Binding (Q)".

[image: cosmic catches screenshot]

I was always under the impression that Bard has only ever been able to stun a maximum of 2 people, not 2+ with a single cast of his Q. So, is there ever a situation where Bard could technically stun more than 2 enemy champions at a time with a single cast?

Comment: For what it's worth, I spent a small amount of time in the practice tool with Bard and some enemy dummies, and it's definitely not possible to stun more than two enemies. I wonder if the "(N+)" is just standard wording for all eternals to clarify what "multiple" actually means, even when there's no possibility of doing more than N.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist I think you should make your own answer. Having your answer baked by test and experience is more interesting than the wiki, plus I think your thought on the N+ format is a good catch which might be worse adding to an answer to be more visible, as it might explain why there is this (2+) in the wording of the ethereal.

Answer (score 1):

Upon looking at the [League of Legends Wiki](https://leagueoflegends.fandom.com/wiki/Bard) (mainly to see if his passive changed), there is not a way for him to stun more than 2 enemies with a single Q.  You should be able to progress by stunning 2 champions.

This is just conjecture but maybe in a future patch, collecting chimes gives additional effects to his spells.  I am only ruling this a possibility since he has fallen out of favor recently and Riot wants to give him more scaling without effecting his early game.  Again though, that is just a guess based on the wording.

Comment: I'm not sure about that second paragraph. Bard's chime scaling was literally just nerfed in [patch 10.5](https://na.leagueoflegends.com/en-us/news/game-updates/patch-10-5-notes/) because he was doing *too well* in high level play. That doesn't really suggest that he's fallen out of favour or they want him to have more scaling.

Comment: I did say it's conjecture though.  It's just something to think about considering the  wording.  Arguably he is not part of the meta at the highest level of play with only 5 games across ALL competitive leagues albeit with a 4-1 record (1 game in EU, 4 games in KR).  The answer still stands regardless of the conjecture.  Rather than leave a comment, next time suggest an edit if a harmless guess about something due to wording really detracts from the correct answer.